# Set image width to span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, width

I have this html code

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="path_to_image1"><span>some text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="path_to_image2"><span>some text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="path_to_image3"><span>some text</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Images are of different width.

I need to set width of SPAN element to be equal as IMG width.
Here is the code that I wrote by looking over the StackOverflow board.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li a").each(function() { 
        var theWidth = $(this).find("img").width();
        $("ul li a span").width(theWidth);
    });
});
```

Now this code returns only width of the last image.
What to change so I can have width of span element same as img?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify: Your `ul` has a specific width for example `100px`. And you want your `li`'s to always be with the same width? So if the `img` is `40px`, then the span has to be `60px`?

Comment: keep in mind that `width` parameter in CSS is not applicable to `inline` elements.  Both `a` and `span` are inline by default, therefore they will not honor `width` attribute.  You can set the width on the actual `li` instead, if this is acceptable.

Comment: @Kalle H. Väravas: in that case span should be 40px

Comment: @Aleks G: Sure. I can add display:block for inline elements too :)

Comment: @Johanatan: you can - but then they won't appear inline - there will be line break before and after each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is in your own code, almost..

```
 $(this).find("span").width(theWidth);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('ul li img').each(function() {
  var imgWidth = $(this).width();
  $(this).next('span').css({'width': imgWidth});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to correct one line:

```
$("ul li a span").width(theWidth);
```

Replace with:

```
$(this).find('span').width(theWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
$("ul li a span").width(theWidth);
```

with

```
$(this).find('span').width(theWidth);
```

Explanation: the line `$("ul li a span").width(theWidth);` sets the width for all three `span` elements.
The 'each' loop runs 3 times.
The *first* time it sets all three spans to the width of the *first* image.
The *second* time it sets all three spans to the width of the *second* image.
...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set the widths of the `<li>`'s to the same width as the image and set the `<span>` as `display: block`;

The spans will then be as wide as their contain (the `<li>`) and it saves you a little extra jquery trying to dig down to span level.

Also, to help speed up your jquery selector simply add an id to the list and target that instead of trying to match `ul li a...`; now all you have to do is match `#widths`.

Example

```
<ul id="widths">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="path_to_image1"><span>some text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="path_to_image2"><span>some text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="path_to_image3"><span>some text</span></a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#widths img').each(function() {
        var imgWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).next('span').css({'width': imgWidth});
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes. Problem is that image is absolute positioned, and I don't know how to center it horizontally :))

Comment: I think centering an absolutely positions element is a case of using 'left: 50%' and 'margin-left: minus <whatever half of the known parent width is>;'...or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways around this, this worked for me though.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul li a img").each(function (index) {
        $(this).next().width($(this).width()).css("display", "block");
    });
});
```